# List Item Data is populated but the data does not display on flat list

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-native-flatlist

In this FlatList, the list items Display but they are blank.
I have set break points and the data is there, but it only displays blank list items.
I think the issue may arise when I am setting the array empty, then it does not re-render properly when the fetch is complete.

**Crypto Component**

```
import {StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {getCrypto} from '../api_service/crypto';
import CryptoItem from '../data/cryptoItem';

export default class CryptoMarket extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {cryptos: [], refreshing: true};
    this.fetchCrypto = this.fetchCrypto.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCrypto();
  }

  fetchCrypto() {
    getCrypto()
      .then(cryptos => this.setState({cryptos, refreshing: false}))
      .catch(() => this.setState({refreshing: false}));
  }
  handleRefresh() {
    this.setState(
      {
        refreshing: true,
      },
      () => this.fetchCrypto(),
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.cryptos}
        renderItem={({item}) => <CryptoItem crypto={{item}} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.name}
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0f0f0f',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    marginTop: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#fff',
  },
});
```

**Fetch API**

```
export async function getCrypto() {
  try {
    const fetchCrypto = await fetch(
      'https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=***&ids=BTC,ETH,XRP',
    );
    const displayCrypto = await fetchCrypto.json();
    console.log(displayCrypto);
    return displayCrypto;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

**List Item**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';

export default class CryptoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const {name, logo_url, price} = this.props.crypto;

    return (
      <ListItem
        title={name}
        text={'Price : ' + price}
        leftAvatar={{source: {uri: logo_url}}}
        bottomDivider={true}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure that the flatlist has full size, try passing style of flex:1 to it

Comment: @HassanKandil I tried that, I also tried to give size to a view parent...